# jQuery(...).fontresizermanager is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function

I've got a problem with jQuery.

```
jQuery.fn.fontresizermanager = function () {

/* too much code... */

}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".inofontResizer").fontresizermanager();
});
```

And this is error:
**jQuery(...).fontresizermanager is not a function**

This is code of simple font resizer plugin for Wordpress.
I'm using it in [CLICK!](http://bwz.uni.lodz.pl/)

Comment: First thing to check obviously would be if the plugin file is included in the html of the page and is located after the jquery itself.

Comment: jQuery is loaded after your plugin. That is the cause of the issue. Load your plugin in footer or after jQuery

Comment: How can I do this? I'm still learning Wordpress...
@update
I made it!
For people who doesn't know how to do this:
`wp_register_script('inofontResizer', $ino_urlpath.'js/jquery.fontsize.js', false,false, true);`
Just add last three arguments to wp_register_script:
first (false) - array
second (false) - version
third (true) - load in footer.

**Thanks a lot!**